# My webRTC APP doesn't work on Heroku (Using simple-peer and socket.io)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, socket.io, webrtc, simple-peer

My webRTC app doesn't work on Heroku, but work on local environment.

My Heroku App: https://rgvc-client.herokuapp.com/

Github client: https://github.com/sayagit/RGVC-client

Github server: https://github.com/sayagit/RGVC-server

**What I want to do:**
If you enter this page, click 'Create Room' button, then your video and audio are played on the browser.
Then you copy address, open and paste the address on new browser, my app starts video chat between two browsers.

**Problem:**
My app can start one video, but can't start another one and any error doesn't occur.

*client/.env(Heroku)*

```
REACT_APP_API=https://rgvc-server.herokuapp.com/
```

*server/.env(Heroku)*

```
CLIENT_URL=https://rgvc-client.herokuapp.com/
```

I'm glad if you have any idea.

Comment: Are you sure you added the correct url in you're env file?. That is the CLIENT_URL key.

Comment: Yes, I added `CLIENT_URL=https://rgvc-client.herokuapp.com/` on Heroku server. And on Heroku client, I added `REACT_APP_API=https://rgvc-server.herokuapp.com/`